# Why does VS 2017 set node_modules folder to read only in .Net Core App?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, asp.net-core

I'm building a .Net Core application using Angular for my client-side code. For the most part, I'm using the default template that is included in VS 2017. For whatever reason, VS is making my node_modules folder read only. Before I was able to install packages via command line in the directory that holds my client side code as well as my package.json file and my node_modules folder. Before I was able to do this, but now it is defaulting the folder to read only which is invaliding all of my npm commands. I've verified that this is the case because I can remove the read only attribute via windows explorer and then run any of my commands like `npm install`.

Has anyone else encountered this before? If so, what did you do to resolve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the answer. VS puts a lock on the node_modules folder while it is running.
So, I guess for now if you need to add packages just close VS first.